Tensorflow Image Data Set is mismatching data and labels
I am attempting to train an binary image classifier (CNN) to detect sad and happy face. I am using the image_dataset_from_directory function to import my data from a directory, where two subdirectories correspond to the two separate classes. After training the model I excised some of the training data and the corresponding labels and compared them. For some reason the labels have been matched incorrectly to the images. I double checked my sorting of the data in the subdirectories and that was correct. The swapping seems to happening somewhere in my code. Where am I going wrong?
data=tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(data_dir, shuffle=True)
#this gives the same result as tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(data_dir)

#post training
training_data= np.concatenate([x for x, y in training_set], axis=0)
training_labels = np.concatenate([y for x, y in training_set], axis=0)

#to compare images and their labels
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=20, figsize=(120,120))
for idx, img in enumerate(training_data[0:20]):
    ax[idx].imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    ax[idx].title.set_text(training_labels[idx])

Was expecting properly matched images and labels, but got a mismatch between them.

Hi @AWM, In the above code, you are facing an issue with a mismatched image. So you are using data shuffling:'shuffle = true‘ Shuffling is good for training to check that the model doesn’t learn the order of the data, but in your case you can try with 'shuffle = false, when you want to analyze your dataset post-training. It will keep the order of the imagers and also check that you are putting the correct indexing.
